# Get the size of std::any

Tags: c++, sizeof, type-erasure, stdany

Is there any way to get the size (in bytes) of the data stored by `std::any`? The only workaround I came up with is querying the type of its value by `std::any::type` and comparing the result to a list of known types like `my_any.type() == typeid(T)`, then the size is `sizeof(T)`. Unfortunately, this solution only works when the types are known beforehand.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: This question is clear and well asked, regardless of the comments, and does not deserve such down voting. (Giving a need for `any::size()` does not much improve the question, tough it may help to expose [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot** get the size of the object held by `std::any` (other than the workaround you've mentioned). `std::any` is a *minimal* implementation of type erasure.

If you want something more powerful, write it yourself (it's not hard, just model it on `std::any` or `boost::any` and add the `size()` functionality).
There are many other things you may want to add to `any`, such as I/O, storing multiple data (or the contents of any container) as arrays, etc..

At the expense of an additional data member (to store the size), you may also extend `std::any` by writing a wrapper, as suggested in Vittorio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730915/1023390).

Answer (score 6):

`std::any` does not provide any way of performing an action on the underlying stored type `T`. However, information like `sizeof(T)` could be available when initializing/assigning to `std::any`.

One possible solution is creating your own wrapper around `std::any` that keeps track of the size. E.g.

```
class my_any : std::any
{ 
    std::size_t _stored_size = 0;

public:
    template <typename T>
    my_any(T&&) : _stored_size{sizeof(std::decay_t<T>)} { }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Probably better to use `std::optional<std::size_t>` than `std::optional<int>` since `sizeof` gives a result of type `std::size_t`.

Comment: Why do we need `std::optional`? Can we just use pure `std::size_t`?

Comment: @DeanSeo `std::size_t` seems a better alternative to me also.

Comment: @Dean what if the any is empty?

Comment: Then the size can be 0 no? Saves a boolean, which after alignment is not nothing.

Comment: @rustyx The size should be `1` instead? Not sure, but in case for `my_any[]`?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Right but even if there's a `std::optional` used, you'd still need to branch its initialization?