# std::vector<std::any> returning the size

Tags: c++, c++17

im trying to get the size of a `std::vector<std::any>`

My function works when the vector is a int but how would i get it to work with std::any

```
template<typename T>
size_t vectorsizeof(const typename std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    return sizeof(T) * vec.size();
}

std::vector<std::any> args = { (int)3, (bool)true };
auto size = vectorsizeof(args);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size of std::any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730735/get-the-size-of-stdany)

Comment: What makes you think it 1) doesn't work, and 2) how exactly do you expect it to work?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? If it is to find the combined size in bytes of the objects that the vector contains, then it is correct. But that information serves practically no purpose. What do you exactly want to find and for what purpose?

Comment: Arguably, getting the size in bytes of a vector of any is a bug as this will ever be useful.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pMemory, args.data(), vectorsizeof(args), nullptr)` this works with a int vector, but does not seem to work with a std::any

Comment: @werico4026 That doesn't work. `std::any` is not a trivially-copyable type. You cannot copy an `std::any` by copying its object representation. If you want to ask why that line doesn't work, I suggest you modify your question so that it asks about exactly that. It has nothing to do with sizes.

Comment: `sizeof(std::any)` is not necessarily related (and, in  general, is unrelated) to the size of whatever an `std::any` contains.   In this case, `sizeof(args[0])` and `sizeof(args[1])` are the same, and unrelated to the fact that `args[0]` contains an `int` and `args[1]` contains a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

> My function works when the vector is a int but how would i get it to
>   work with std::any
>
> ```
> return sizeof(T) * vec.size();
> ```

This function already works with `std::any` as well as it works with `int`. Assuming the intention is to return the size of the dynamic array of the vector in bytes.

> `WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pMemory, args.data(), vectorsizeof(args), nullptr)` this works with a int vector, but does not seem to work with a std::any

Indeed. That can only work with trivially copyable types. `int` is trivially copyable. `std::any` is not trivially copyable. The problem is not with `vectorsizeof`. Knowing the size of the object will not help you copy non-trivially-copyable objects byte-wise.

Communicating non-trivial data structures across processes necessitates translating it into a format that can represent the structure as raw bytes. Such translation is called *serialisation*. There is no way to serialise `std::any`, but it may be possible to serialise whatever type the `std::any` contains, if you know that type.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::any` instances do not know the underlying type of the objects they hold, so they do not know the size of the type either.

However you can make a wrapper to `std::any` that remembers the size.

```
class any_with_size : std::any{
    template<class T> any_with_size(T const& t) : std::any(t), s_{sizeof(T)}{}
    template<class T> any_with_size& operator=(T const& t){s_ = sizeof(T); std::any::operator==(t); return *this;}
    ...
    std::size_t dynamic_sizeof() const{return s_;}
private:
    std::size_t s_;
}
```

This gets closer to something called type erasure if you start adding functions that you know can be applied to some particular set of types.