# Using std::memcpy to copy an object that contains a boost::any data member

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, memcpy, boost-any

I am trying to pass an object that contains a `boost::any` data member through a networking API to exchange data between two applications. I know that the API uses `memcpy` internally to copy the data, but I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is invoking undefined behavior.

I wrote up a simple example to demonstrate using `memcpy` in this way:

```cpp
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Data
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Data(T value)
        : m_value(value)
    {}

    template <typename T>
    T Read() const
    {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(m_value);
    }

private:
    boost::any m_value;
};

int main()
{
    Data src(std::string("This is some data."));
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof(src) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SRC: " << src.Read<std::string>() << std::endl;

    void* dst = malloc(sizeof(src));
    std::memcpy(dst, &src, sizeof(src));

    const auto data = static_cast<Data*>(dst);
    std::cout << "DST: " << data->Read<std::string>() << std::endl;

    std::free(dst);
}
```

This code appears to work, and prints the following output:

```
Size: 8
SRC: This is some data.
DST: This is some data.
```

But depending on the type stored in the `Data` object wouldn't the size change? No matter what type I use it always prints that the size is `8`.

Is this code invoking undefined behavior? If it is, how can I fix it so I can properly `memcpy` an object that contains a `boost::any` data member?

Comment: `sizeof ( boost::any)` is a constant. It is always the same, no matter what type it holds.

Comment: Generally you should *never* use `std::memcpy` to copy any C++ object. It will do a byte-wise straight copy, and won't invoke copy-constructors which means complex objects might not be copied in a valid way.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730735/get-the-size-of-stdany

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't have a choice in this case because the `memcpy` is called internally inside the networking API. I just need to make sure the type I pass to it can validly be copied using `memcpy`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number does this mean that this is well defined and I can do it this way?

Comment: this is also related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable. If it isnt `is_trivially_copyable` then you cannot just memcpy it, because copying it needs more than copying bits and bytes. `any` certainly isnt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`any` contains a pointer, and has a destructor, and is overall something you don't want to `memcpy`. It's working here because both `src` and `dst` are in the same memory space and because you’re `free`ing the object without running the destructor.

It's potentially okay to `memcpy` the pointed-to object held by the `any` (the object returned by `any_cast`). It is definitely *not* okay to `memcpy` the `any` itself, or an object containing it.

Comment: No double-free because the second object is not a Data, but a raw pointer to Data that is freed via `std:free` which doesn't run destructors. OP is lucky that a memcpy'd `std::string` "sort of works if the original hasn't been destroyed and you don't try anything funny with it." Would definitely not work cross-process.

Comment: Good catch, I saw `free` and thought `delete`.